# Xdebug with VS Code on ubuntu not working

Tags: php, ubuntu, zend-framework, xdebug

I am trying to debug php using xdebug on ubuntu 16.04 with Visual Studio code. I installed xdebug as per the instructions from the following site-[Xdebug wizard](https://xdebug.org/wizard.php). In the xampp the php version is shown as **PHP Version 5.5.6** but when i run the command *php -v* in terminal, it shows

> PHP 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4 (cli) ( NTS )
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
>   with Zend OPcache v7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4, Copyright (c) 1999-2017,
>    by Zend Technologies

I don't know if that may cause any problem. But, the real issue is that Debugger doesn't stop at any breakpoints. Also, it sometimes shows **unverified breakpoint** message. Sometimes it just runs and never stop at any breakpoints. The Xdebug options don't fully show up in *phpinfo()* page even after the installation. I don't understand the problem.

Comment: the problem is you installed xdebug for 5.5, but your xampp is using 7.0. Either change version, or install xdebug for 7.0

Comment: i have upgraded xampp to php7 and reinstalled xdebug...still it does not work... when i use "Launch Chrome" configuration on vs code, it shows "Breakpoint ignored because generated code not found (source map problem?)."

Answer (score 2):

make sure you have configure xdebug.ini file. here mine.

```js
     [xdebug]
     zend_extension=xdebug.so
     xdebug.remote_autostart=1
     xdebug.remote_log=/var/log/apache2/xdebug.log
     xdebug.default_enable = 1
     xdebug.remote_enable=1
     xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

Comment: Thanks, I added the xdebug configuration to my dev environment in `/etc/php/7.x/cli/php.ini` and it worked.

Answer (score -3):

**sudo apt-get install php-xdebug**

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.